# Expected known function, got 'count',how can I use count in doctorine?

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have table like this 
reviews in restaurant table are tied as foreign key with reviews table

```
Restaurant table

ID| name      | reviews
1 | subway    | 1,2
2 | macdonald | 3

Review table

ID| review
1 | review about subway1
2 | review about subway2
3 | review about macdonald
```

Normally I can fetch Resturant data as

```
$query = $this->em->createQuery(
                "SELECT a FROM Restaurant a);
```

However I would like to order the number of review column.
Now I made sentence like this but in vain.

```
$query = $this->em->createQuery(
        "SELECT a FROM Restaurant a 
            INNER JOIN Review r 
            order by count(a.reviews) ");
```

it shows error like this.

Expected known function, got 'count'

Answer (score 1):

You should have the restaurant ID in the reviews table, so that you skip the complications of having a comma-separated string in the restaurant table.

```
Restaurant table

ID| name      
1 | subway    
2 | macdonald 

Review table

ID| restaurant ID | review
1 | 1             | review about subway1
2 | 1             | review about subway2
3 | 2             | review about macdonald
```

Then you can do this:

```
$query = $this->em->createQuery(
    "SELECT a, count(a.reviews) count1 FROM Restaurant a 
        INNER JOIN Review r 
        order by count1 ");
```